# How to check presence of element in regular time interval with Selenium and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

In order to check particular element on regular time interval basis, we do following using Java:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                   .withTimeout(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(element);
```

Are there api's in Ruby to implement the same? If yes, please help me by giving the code.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Comment: There is no way mentioned to achieve like above code in java

Comment: Did you check? I can see an "explicit wait" section on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API linked there gives this example

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "foo") }
```

Here are the docs for that `Wait` class
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Wait.html

You just need to set the `:timeout` (withTimeout) `:interval` (pollingEvery), and `:ignore` (ignoring) options when you instantiate your `Wait` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But when I tried to define wait with `:ignore` parameter like 'wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 4, :ignore => NoSuchElementError)' it throws error `uninitialized constant NoSuchElementError` It also throws error when I use `Error:NoSuchElementError` Could you please help me to understand how to pass value `:ignore`? I know `Error:NoSuchElementError` is default for `:ignore` but I want to try with some other hence I'm asking.

Comment: `Error::NoSuchElementError`, but that's in the docs as well. It's also the default ignored value.

Comment: Yes, but when I pass the same `Error::NoSuchElementError` it's throwing error `NameError: uninitialized constant Error` Thank you for your answer! Accepted :)

Comment: Got it now :) :) I was putting only `Error::NoSuchElementError` instead of `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError` Now, it works!!!

Comment: @ThatUmbrellaGuy looks like your link is dead